# URI rewrite with nginx and php-fpm with parameters

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of different rules on my nginx server with php-fpm.

The simple one is a rewrite that changes http://server/$1?param=1 to http://server/$1.php?param=1 using

```
location @extensionless-php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

I also need to rewrite http://server/abc/123 to http://server/abc.php/123 and also have this processed by the php-fpm

This is the fast-cgi code:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

}
```

and this is the location rewrite

```
location @abc-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)/abc/(.*)$ $1/photo.php/$2 last;
}
```

But I keep getting a 404. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how the named location `@abc-php` is invoked. I suspect that you have something like this to managed the extensionless PHP:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}
```

Your new rewrite rule can be added to the existing named location, like this:

```
location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)/abc/(.*)$ $1/photo.php/$2 last;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

However, your fast-cgi block is incapable of handing the path_info, so you will need to [look here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for conventional wisdom, or use something like this:

```
location ~ ^(?<script>.*\.php)(?<pathinfo>.*)$ {
    try_files $script =404;
    include fastcgi_params; 
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $pathinfo;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: I used a mix of your solution and the conventional wisdom -- largely due to some particularly complex structures in the php filename. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.